# WPF Resizing DataGrid with content

Tags: wpf, datagrid, wpf-controls

So all the questions I've seen so far are about resizing the columns to the content, but I want to resize the whole control - the datagrid itself - and change the width (and height) to be that of the columns - basically so that there's no wasted space to the right/below. Therefore, of course, if the data is wider (or taller) than the current size of the datagrid then I don't want it to expand - only to shrink if required. Is there a built-in thing for this, or do I have to programmatically calculate the actual width of each column?

For example, if I make a dataGrid and set it to Width=200; - but the content turns out to only take up 150px of width, I want the dataGrid to then resize to be 150px wide. Of course the grid will be read only and the user won't be able to resize the columns, so it would only have to do this at population.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't u just set the `width/height="Auto"` and also set the `MinWidth` and `MinHeight` in that datagrid?